# map domain to subdomain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, subdomain, mapping

I'm working on a project where people can sign up and have multiple shops for themselves.  Let's consider that **Mark** signed up to our site and created a shop for himself:

```
markshop.shop.com
```

Now, mark wants to map a domain called **markshop.com** to **markshop.shop.com**.

How do I go about this in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a simple "CNAME" record in DNS.  A CNAME record is an alias of an "A" record.  An A record is a host to ip mapping.

So in your case, the following would be true:

A Record would be "Markshop.shop.com" = 192.168.7.7 (just an example)
CNAME Record would be "markshop.com" = Markshop.shop.com

Now I will say, typically your main domain (zone) would be an A record, so in this case markshop.com *should* probably be an A record that points to 192.168.7.7 and then www.markshop.com should alias to markshop.com (CNAME record), but i think you might be able to get away with a CNAME depending on your DNS setup.

Comment: He will, however, also have to tell you that he's using that domain and you'll have to configure that in your server. Otherwise, when you get requests for host "markshop.com", you'll have no way to know you should serve the web pages for "markshop.shop.com".

Comment: Good point, so you're basically saying he'll need host headers configured in IIS.